# .htaccess redirect still goes to 404

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite in my .htaccess file, it is still landing on a 404 instead of redirecting.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tab=auto_data(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.example.com/automobile-data/ [L,R=301]
```

There are multiple pages that can possibly have the `tab=auto_data` query string parameter, and there are quite possibly other QSP appended behind `tab=auto_data` as well.

I need to redirect any URL that contains the QSP of `tab=auto_data` to a new page in the site. The domain would remain the same, just the page name is changing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the URL of the request? Is there anything from the request you need in the target (ie. any reason to capture a group in the `RewriteRule` pattern)? Presumably you have `RewriteEngine` etc? Any other directives in your .htaccess file? Incidentally, you don't need `(.*)$` on the end of the _CondPattern_.

Comment: The only other directives are the standard WordPress directives. I'm not super familiar with this stuff, but `RewriteEngine` engine is on. If I understand your question correctly, the incoming URL would be `https://test.example.com/polk/?tab=auto_data` and should be redirected to  `https://test.example.com/automobile-data/`.

Comment: "The domain would remain the same" - actually, if the above did do _anything_ it would result in a redirect loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only other directives are the standard WordPress directives.

In that case, your *external redirect* should come *before* any WordPress routing directives. The `RewriteEngine` directive only needs to appear once, anywhere, in the file. Although it is obviously more logical if it occurs once at the top.

You also need to remove the query string from the substitution, otherwise you'll get a redirect loop since the domain is the same. If the domain/host remains the same then this can be omitted from the substitution.

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tab=auto_data
RewriteRule ^polk/$ /automobile-data/? [R=301,L]
```

This specifically matches only the URL-path `/polk/` (as mentioned in comments), unless this needs to be more general? And `tab=auto_data` must match anywhere in the query string.

The `?` on the end of the substitution removes the query string and so prevents a redirect loop. (Presumably the query string should be removed from the target?) Although since the source and target URL paths are different, this is not strictly necessary anymore.

If the "domain remains the same", then there is no specific *need* to include the scheme and host in the substitution. Unless you are hosting multiple domains etc.?

Make sure the browser cache is cleared before testing as 301s are notorious for caching. Testing with 302s can be preferable for this reason.

**UPDATE:** To specifically remove this query string parameter, but copy the remaining query string onto the target, try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tab=auto_data(?:&(.+))?
RewriteRule ^polk/$ /automobile-data/?%1 [R=301,L]
```

`(?:&(.+))?` - grabs any remaining query string (if any), but excludes the `&` prefix (param delimiter) from the captured group. `%1` is a backreference to this captured group.

Comment: This allowed the redirect to work correctly; however any additional query string parameters after `tab=auto_data` were lost and did not follow through and get appended on the new URL.

Comment: Since we are only targeting `/polk/` URLs (which is different from the substitution), then you could remove the `?` on the end of the substitution. This will also allow the `tab=auto_data` param through as well.

Comment: To clarify this some, the `tab=auto_data` is not needed any longer after the redirect, but if there are additional query string parameters they are needed as they alter content and settings on the site.

Comment: Even removing the `?` isn't allowing any params to be carried over.

Comment: Is `tab=auto_data` _always_ at the start of the query string?

Comment: Always at the start.

Comment: After removing the `?` you'll need to clearing your browser cache. (As mentioned, test with 302s and change to 301 only when you are sure it's working OK. And/or test with caching disabled in the browser.)

Comment: I tried a new browser, all params carried over while the `?` is removed from the end of the substitution.

Comment: I'm definitely accepting this answer, thanks so much for your help. If you know of a way to exclude `tab=auto_data` from carrying over but allowing all other params I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a method for removing just that URL parameter, but keeping the remaining.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121848/discussion-between-andywarren-and-w3dk).